# How can I insert a dataframe in Excel using xlwings without pywintypes.com_error?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlwings

I am using Excel and xlwings. I have a book.xlsm, on the first sheet there is a button assigned to the following vba code:

```
book.xlsm!ThisWorkbook.get_data
```

On the VBA I have added this which when the button is called and the vba code executed, it runs:

```
Sub get_data()
    RunPython ("import my_script; my_script.get_data()")
End Sub
```

The my_script is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from xlwings import Workbook, Range

def get_data():
    wb = Workbook.caller()

    df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
    Range("Sheet2", "A1").value = df
```

The problem I encounter is the following:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147024882, 'Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.', None, None)
```

The data.csv file has 150000 rows and 120 rows. Using less data it runs without error.

**Update:** Currently there is not a solution, but there is a workaround as provided in the comments: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/77

I use the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, na_values={"", " ", "-"})
df.fillna("-", inplace=True)
startcell = 'A1'
chunk_size = 2500
if len(df) <= (chunk_size + 1):
    Range(sheet_name, startcell, index=False).value = df
else:  # chunk df and and dump each (default is 10k)\n",
    c = re.match(r"([a-z]+)([0-9]+)", startcell, re.I)
    cL = c.group(1)
    cN = int(c.group(2))
    n = 0
    for i in (df[rw:rw + chunk_size] for rw in xrange(0, len(df), chunk_size)):
        if n == 0:
            Range(sheet_name, cL + str(cN+n), index=False).value = i
            cN += chunk_size
        else:
            Range(sheet_name, cL + str(cN+n)).value = i.values
            cN += chunk_size
        n += 1
```

The problem I encounter is that when I insert the data in the sheet there is an empty line at 5002, again at 7503, 10004.... I realize there's a mistake in my code but I can't find it.

Comment: there is already an issue open for that with a workaround for now: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/77

Comment: Currently I open the csv and insert the lines 15000 at a time, but it takes 90 seconds. The workaround seems more efficient. Is there a way to insert an existing sheet containing the data in the workbook I use ?

Comment: Currently there is no such solution, but follow the discussion on the github issue for updates in the future.

Answer (score 3):

There is a workaround function posted on the [GitHub issue page](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/77). It divides the DataFrame into smaller chunks and inserts them into Excel. Unfortunately, as you have noticed, the function is bugged and causes an empty row to appear between chunks.

I modified the function and now it's working perfectly.

```
# Dumps a large DataFrame in Excel via xlwings.
# Does not include headers.
def dump_largeDF(df, startcell='A1', chunk_size=100000):
    if len(df) <= (chunk_size + 1):
        Range(startcell, index=False, header=False).value = df
    else: # Chunk df and and dump each
        c = re.match(r"([a-z]+)([0-9]+)", startcell, re.I) # A1
        row = c.group(1) # A
        col = int(c.group(2)) # 1
        for chunk in (df[rw:rw + chunk_size] for rw in
                      range(0, len(df), chunk_size)):
            print("Dumping chunk in %s%s" %(row, col))
            Range(row + str(col), index=False, header=False).value = chunk
            col += chunk_size
```

For me, a chunk size of 100k is fine, however you may change it depending on your needs.

Comment: is there a similar solution for reading back from a range and into a dataframe in chunks using xlwings?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to resurrect an old thread.

When I run the above function as a call from another function, I get a variety of errors, mostly around the `Range` item. Would it be possible to write this function "independently" such that it includes `import` and the target `wb`? I had:

```
def dump_largeDF(wb, df, sheetName, startcell, chunk_size):
    import pandas as pd
    import xlwings as xw
    import re

    if len(df) <= (chunk_size + 1):
        wb.sheets(sheetName).Range(startcell, index=False, header=False).value = df
    else: # Chunk df and and dump each
        c = re.match(r"([a-z]+)([0-9]+)", startcell, re.I) # A1
        row = c.group(1) # A
        col = int(c.group(2)) # 1
        for chunk in (df[rw:rw + chunk_size] for rw in range(0, len(df), chunk_size)):
            wb.sheets(sheetName).Range(row + str(col), index=False, header=False).value = chunk
            col += chunk_size
```

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who is keen on also correctly handling the header and not relying on the Range, I modified the code a bit:

```
def dumpLargeDf(wb, df, startcell='A1', chunk_size=50000):
    # Dumps a large DataFrame in Excel via xlwings. Takes care of header.
    if len(df) <= (chunk_size + 1):
        wb.sheets.active.range(startcell).options(index=False).value = df
    else:                                       # Chunk df and and dump each
        c = re.match(r"([a-z]+)([0-9]+)", startcell, re.I)      # A1
        row = c.group(1)                                        # A
        col = int(c.group(2))                                   # 1
        useHeader = True
        for chunk in (df[rw:rw + chunk_size] for rw in
                      range(0, len(df), chunk_size)):
            print("Dumping chunk in %s%s" % (row, col))
            wb.sheets.active.range(row + str(col)) \
                .options(index=False, header=useHeader).value = chunk
            useHeader = False
            col += chunk_size
```